# MySQL counting record vs storing a counter

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that stores the user feedback of a post, something like this

```
Table: user_feedback. Feedback_id is PRI AI
Feedback_id     Post_id     User_id
1                  1          1     
2                  2          1
3                  1          3
4                  1          4
5                  5          1
```

In my posts table I currently have something like this:

```
Table: posts
Post_id   Likes
1           3
2           1
5           1
```

I increment the likes counter every time a post is liked and then to get the number of likes a post has I just run

```
SELECT likes FROM posts WHERE post_id = 1;
```

But is this worth the trouble (example, storing the feedback and MySQL somehow fails to increment the counter) of maintaining it and is it even any faster? How much faster is to then just:

```
SELECT COUNT(feedback_id) FROM user_feedback WHERE post_id = 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is de-normalized but we have seen worse. It is common practice but susceptible to error. However, if the insert to feedback can be wrapped in a transaction: the feedback insert happens **AND** the update to `Likes` both succeed, or else the transaction is rolled back.

There is the benefit for substantial increase in performance by having this `Likes` column. It is a thin datatype size, and if you combine it in a `covered index` (composite) with post_id, then on queries for `post_id`,`Likes` it is completely available in the index page without the db engine going after the data page (not to mention not requiring a join). Saw this last night with someone with tens of millions of rows getting snappy output.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT COUNT response time will degrade as your data grows. I would go with the first option. However, using a relational database for this may be an overkill, perhaps you should take a look into memory caches that persist to disk in background, and things like that (redis, guava, memcache, etc).

Also, if this number is not "mission critical" you could live with an update failing now and then.